# The value range (minimum & maximum)

Tags: c++, range, definition

What exactly the maximum and the minimum value of any definition type? Is this possible?

```
unsigned int maximum_uint = (maximum_value)(unsigned int);
short minimum_short = (minimum_value)(short);
float maximum_float = (maximum_value)(float);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <limits>

unsigned int maximum_uint = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();
short minimum_short = std::numeric_limits<short>::min();
float maximum_float = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
```

Comment: You forgot the `std::` qualification (or an apprpriate `using` statement).

Answer (score 2):

What you have written is probably not possible.

The limits of various types are provided in the *C-style* C++ header `climits` and some in the C++ header `limits`

See :

[`climits`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/)

[`limits`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/)

Comment: Great, I was not knowing this. But it will really help.

Comment: There is no `climits.h` header. There is only `limits.h` (which is deprecated), `climits` (which is the C++ version of C's `limits.h`) and `limits` (which should be preferred over the other two, anyway).

Comment: @ChristianRau Thanks for pointing that out. Typo. I meant climits

Comment: @ChristianRau I dont understand what you mean by that. I made the change

Comment: @AshRj That change wasn't that severe, since `limits.h` exists pretty well (even if being deprecated). What doesn't exist is `climits.h`. But never mind, doing it myself.